# Java - use search results from ArrayList/HashSet query for menu selection

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm wondering if anyone can give me some pointers on what the next steps in a basic program I have.

I have the following example java code:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    ArrayList<Transport> transportList = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void addToList() {
        transportList.add(new Transport("Blue", "Large", "Plane"));
        transportList.add(new Transport("Red", "Small", "Car"));
        transportList.add(new Transport("Brown", "Large", "Train"));
        transportList.add(new Transport("Yellow", "Small", "Boat"));
        transportList.add(new Transport("Yellow", "Small", "Plane"));
        transportList.add(new Transport("Brown", "Large", "Car"));
        transportList.add(new Transport("Red", "Large", "Train"));
        transportList.add(new Transport("Blue", "Small", "Boat"));

        searchColour();
    }

    public void searchColour() {
        System.out.println("Enter a colour to search:\n");
        String colourSearch = input.next();
        for (Transport transport : transportList) {
            if (transport.getColour().toLowerCase().equals(colourSearch.toLowerCase())) {
                System.out.printf(
                    "There is a %s %s that is %s \n",
                    transport.getSize(),
                    transport.getType(),
                    transport.getColour()
                );
            }
        }
        searchColour();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().addToList();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Transport {

    private String colour;
    private String size;
    private String type;

    // All-args constructor, getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

This runs and prompts the user to enter a colour. It then searches the ArrayList and outputs the matches.
What I now need to do is to take the results I get from a colour search and reuse them in a menu for selection.

For example if I search for "red", I get:

There is a Small Car that is Red

There is a Large Train that is Red

What I want is to have a number placed in front of them and another prompt to choose which one the person whats. So it should say something like:

1. There is a Small Car that is Red
2. There is a Large Train that is Red

"Choose which transport you want"

Outputting the next question and prompting for an input with Scanner I can do, I'm not sure how I can add numbers to the start of the results, knowing that as my ArrayList grows the number of items will, and how I do a selection choice from it so a user can press 1 or 2.

Can anyone offer a suggestion? I'm thinking I need to use another ArrayList but I'm not sure how this should be structured.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You variable and class names are a bit confusing. I would suggest to call the transport Object `Transport`.  List is kind of occupied by the Java List interface. Then in your `Main` class you would have an `ArrayList<Transport>`.  The list could be named `transports` or `transportList`. That would make the code much more readable.

Comment: Save the matches in new ArrayLIst. Use the indexes when iterating over it to print the number and the transport. As a side note you have created infinite recursion for `searchColour()`, with high enough number of inputs you will certainly get `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Thanks for the input @DrHopfen, this was a quick example code however you are correct, I shouldn't have used 'List'

Comment: @Chaosfire, the example code i did was a quick test case for my actual code that's a bit more in depth, I just wanted to provide an example that could show my search case. My actual code just does the search once and then either exits out of the For loop or would include my later code to provide a menu if I manage to come up with one. However I appreciate the input, having it being mention will help it stick in my head

Comment: And I now realise (combined with my response below) what @Chaosfire means. I attempt to code a new ArrayList with adds, and use IndexOf() to get the number. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make use of the fact, that an ArrayList keeps the elements in insertion order. You could e.g. use the "indexOf(Object o)" method to get the number you want to be printed. (You have to add 1 to get your example, because it starts with 0.)

And to select the item you can use "get(int index)" and let the user type the index. (here you have to substract 1, like above.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments @LukasB, I've now attempted this with the code 

`System.out.printf(transportList.indexOf(transport) + ". There is a %s %s that is %s \n", transport.getSize(), transport.getType(),
      transport.getColour());` which includes previous comments for better variable names. 
However this does tie in with what @Chaosfire said, I get the result

3. There is a Small Boat that is Yellow 

4. There is a Small Plane that is Yellow

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a counter.  Create an `int` variable to keep track of the question number.

When the user inputs a number, use the List’s [get](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#get(int)) method to retrieve the choice:

```
public void searchColour() {
    System.out.println("Enter a colour to search:\n");
    String colourSearch = input.next();

    List<Transport> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    int questionNumber = 1;
    for (Transport transport : transportList) {
        if (transport.getColour().toLowerCase().equals(colourSearch.toLowerCase())) {
            matches.add(transport);
            System.out.printf(
                "%d. There is a %s %s that is %s \n",
                questionNumber++,
                transport.getSize(),
                transport.getType(),
                transport.getColour()
            );
        }
    }

    int choice;
    do {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Choose which transport you want:");
        choice = input.nextInt();
    } while (choice < 1 || choice > matches.size());

    // List indices start at zero, not one.
    Transport transport = matches.get(choice - 1);

    System.out.printf("You chose a %s %s that is %s%n",
                transport.getSize(),
                transport.getType(),
                transport.getColour()
}
```

The `println` method prints a newline after printing the argument you pass it.  Therefore, you don’t need to pass a String ending with `\n`, unless you really want to print a blank line after the text (and that may not work in Windows, where a newline sequence is actually the two characters `\r\n`).

In the `printf` method, you can use the special Formatter sequence `%n` instead of a literal `\n` to make sure the system’s newline sequence is always used.

Comment: Thanks @VGR, you've pointed on a good track for the number option, a simple but effective solution.

However I need to rework the second bit as while the choice input is taken, it's returning the entry at the index of the main array not the actual choice presented from the result. I believe I may need to add to another arraylist, which I'll attempt. Thanks for the input

Comment: Also i've seen this '\n' vs '%n' when I played around with my code in VS Code, I use another IDE as my main one, but when I run it in my current IDE, the new line character does not take effect, it seems I need to use \n while I'm using printf.

Comment: @JohnRehill Ah, right you are. Updated code to have a new List containing the matched transports.